# Javascript tooltips for SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg

I have one SVG which works as a top bar with some headlines. It consists of many rectangles with some text and I would like to show tooltips for each of them when user mouseover it.

I tried to implement something like [this](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/tooltip_basic.svg) but I need to keep the .js code in separate file, because I am generating my svg files dynamically. However, nothing happens when I mouseover my elements (rectangles in the svg). I think taht the problem micht be with referencing my svg in the script but I am not sure what is wrong.

Here is the exmaple of my code (I deleted some non-important parts to keep it readable.)

**SVG:**

```
    <svg contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" width="760" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" zoomAndPan="magnify" contentStyleType="text/css"
    height="140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        onload="init(evt)" version="1.0">
    <script xlink:href="script.js" xlink:actuate="onLoad" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="other" type="text/ecmascript" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/><rect x="0" width="120" height="140" y="0" 
    style="fill:#DEE7EF"/><rect x="120" y="0" width="30" style="fill:#9CAAC6" 
    onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)" height="140" onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 
    &apos;BlueServiceESB#BlueListener&apos;)"><text fill="black" x="0" id="tooltip" font-
    size="10" y="0" visibility="hidden">BlueServiceESB#BlueListener</text></rect></svg>
```

I know it might look confusing, if so, I will try to replace my text elements with some other stuff to make it more readable, let me know in comments...

My **script.js** file

```
// tooltip
function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext)
{
    tooltip.setAttribute("x",evt.clientX+11);
    tooltip.setAttribute("y",evt.clientY+27);
    tooltip.firstChild.data = mouseovertext;
    tooltip.setAttribute("visibility","visible");
}

function HideTooltip(evt)
{
    tooltip.setAttribute("visibility","hidden");
}

// init for tooltip functions
function init(evt)
{
    if ( window.svgDocument == null )
    {
    svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
    }

    tooltip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip');

}
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the init function and just find the tooltip element each time. So your script will look like:

```
function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext) {
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    tooltip.setAttribute("x", evt.clientX + 11);
    tooltip.setAttribute("y", evt.clientY + 27);
    tooltip.firstChild.data = mouseovertext;
    tooltip.setAttribute("visibility", "visible");
}

function HideTooltip(evt) {
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    tooltip.setAttribute("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

I think there's also a couple of issues with the SVG (maybe because of the way it's generated). The most important point is to not wrap the `text` in the `rect` element. This works:

```
    <svg width="760" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0">

        <rect x="0" width="120" height="140" y="0" style="fill:#DEE7EF" />
        <rect x="120" y="0" width="30" height="140" style="fill:#9CAAC6"
            onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)" 
            onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, &apos;BlueServiceESB#BlueListener&apos;)" />

        <text x="0" y="0" width="20" height="10" fill="black" id="tooltip" font-size="10"  visibility="hidden">BlueServiceESB#BlueListener</text>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

1) First off all you should use ';' ( style="fill:#9CAAC6;" ) in style attribute and every js code  ( onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt);" )

2) Change

```
onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)"
```

to

```
onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt); return false;"
```

3) I think that easy to use jquery instead native js

I) Add an id for your shape(in your case rect)

II) Make

```
$('#rect_id').on('mouseover',function(e){
   // do your stuff here
});
$('#rect_id').on('mouseout',function(e){
   // do your stuff here
});
```

As an example take a look at http://jqvmap.com/. Tooltip implemented there as i wrote above.

Comment: Thanks for response, can you explain more the 3) part? I am generating my svg code in java, so I cant jsut copy it and try it if I dont undestand it well (I am using Apache Batik)

Comment: 1) Download jQuery
2) set an id attribute to your shape <rect id='my_rect'></rect>
3) add js
 $('#my_rect').on('mouseover',function(e){
   // show tooltip here
});
$('#my_rect').on('mouseout',function(e){
   // hide tooltip here
});

Comment: I don't think the jQuery library is the correct tool for this job. You are suggesting adding 99% unnecessary JavaScript for a simple `mouseover/mouseout`

Comment: it isn't only  mouseover/mouseout, addlistener should be here too to make this sample work. jQuery provides it more easier and readable. And you are 99% right, but i think that Smajl is new in js.

Comment: Point 1 is not correct. You only need to use semi-colons to separate styles: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StyleAttribute